# How to use the ncp parameter in R's qt function?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I'm using R to make some calculations. This question is about R but also about statistics.

Say I have a dataset of paired samples consisting of a subject's blood platelet concentration after injection of placebo and then again after injection of medication for a number of subjects. I want to estimate the mean difference for the paired samples. I'm just learning about the t distribution. If I wanted to a 95% confidence interval for the mean difference using a Z-test, I could simply use:

```
mydata$diff <- mydata$medication - mydata$placebo
mu0 <- mean(mydata$diff)
sdmu <- sd(mydata$diff) / sqrt(length(mydata$diff))
qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), mu, sdmu)
```

After much confusion and cross-checking with the `t.test` function, I've figured out that I can get the 95% confidence interval for a t-test with:

```
qt(c(0.025, 0.975), df=19) * sdmu + mu0
```

My understanding of this is as follows:

```
Tstatistic = (mu - mu0)/sdmu
Tcdf^-1(0.025) <= (mu - mu0) / sdmu <= Tcdf^-1(0.975)
=>
sdmu * Tcdf^-1(0.025) + mu0 <= mu <= sdmu * Tcdf^-1(0.975) + mu0
```

The reason this is confusing is that if I were using a Z-test, I would write it like this:

```
qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), mu0, sdmu)
```

and it's not until I tried to figure out how to use the t distribution that I realised I could move the normal distribution parameters out of the function too:

```
qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), 0, 1) * sdmu + mu0
```

Trying to wrap my head around what this means mathematically, it means that the Z-statistic (mu - mu0)/sdmu is always normally distributed with mean 0 and standard deviation of 1?

What has me stumped is that I'd like to move the t distribution parameters into the arguments to the function to cut down on the enormous mental overhead of thinking about this transformation.

However, according to my version of the R function `qt`'s documentation, in order to do this, I would need to calculate the *non-centrality parameter* ncp. According to (my version of) the documentation, the ncp is explained as follows:

```
Let T= (mX - m0) / (S/sqrt(n)) where mX is the mean and S the sample standard deviation (sd) of X_1, X_2, …, X_n which are i.i.d. N(μ, σ^2) Then T is distributed as non-central t with df= n - 1 degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter ncp = (μ - m0) * sqrt(n)/σ.
```

I can't wrap my head around this at all. At first it seems to fit into my framework because `Tstatistic = (mu - m0) / sdmu`. But isn't μ what I want the `qt` function (which is Tcdf-1) to *return*? How can it appear in the ncp, which I need to give as an input? And what about σ? What do μ and σ mean in this context?

Basically, how can I get the same result as `qt(c(0.025, 0.975), df=19) * sdmu + mu0`, without any terms outside of the function call, and could I have an explanation of how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain without using any formulae.

First of all, the student t distribution and the normal distribution are two distinct probability distributions and (in most situations) are not supposed to give you the same results.

The t distribution is the appropriate probability distribution to test for a difference between two normally distributed samples. Since we do not know the population sd we have to stick with the one we get from the sample. And that distribution is not normal distributed anymore, it is t-distributed.

The z-distribution can be used to approximate the test. In this case, we use the z-distribution as approximation of the t-distribution. However, it is recommended not to do this with low degrees of freedom. Reason: the higher degrees of freedom a t distribution has it becomes increasingly similar to a normal distribution. Textbooks usually say that t and normal distribution with df>30 are similar enough to approximate t with normal distribution. In order to do that, you would have to normalise your data, first, so that mean = 0 and sd = 1. Then you can do the approximation using the z-distribution.

I usually recommend *not* to use this approximation. It was a reasonable crutch when calculations had to be done on paper using your head, a pen, and a bunch of tables. There exist many workarounds in basic statistics that were supposed to give you a reasonble result with less computation effort. With modern computers that is usually obsolete (in most cases at least).

The z distribution, by the way, is defined (by convention) as a normal distribution N(0, 1) i.e. a normal distribution with mean = 0 and sd = 1.

Finally, about the different ways these distributions are specified. The normal distribution is actually the only probability distribution that I know that you can specify by setting mean and sd directly (there are dozens of distributions, in case you're interested). The non-centrality parameter has a similar effect than the mean of the normal distribution. In a plot it moves the t-distribution along the x-axis. But it also changes its shape and skews it so that mean and ncp move away from each other.

This code will show how the ncp changes the shape and location of the t-distribution:

```
x <- seq(-5, 15, 0.1)
plot(x, dt(x, df = 10, ncp = 0), from = -4, to = +4, type = "l")
for(ncp in 1:6)
  lines(x, dt(x, df = 10, ncp = ncp))
```

Comment: Ah, so whereas reparameterizing the normal distribution is equivalent to translation plus scaling, changing the parameters of the t distribution changes its *shape* nonlinearly, which is why you can't do the same thing. Thank you!